# declare hibernate POJO boolean properties which not mapped with column

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

In Candidate  POJO i have boolean property "isNewCandidate"

So what is the best approach for that variable declare in POJO so that struts can access it.

```
<s:property value="candidate.isNewCandidate"/>
```

So i make the property public and i was able to access it. But should i make the property public or is there a best way i can have property private and have getters and setters like normal database column map properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property has to be public for Struts or the UI to access it. So the other answer is incorrect.

You could make it a read-only property, if you can figure it out from within the Candidate object (for example, if ID is non-zero).

However, it might be better to figure it out in the controller & just set it in the view (ie, set it as a request-attribute) rather than adding it to the bean. JSPs can read & render from request-attributes.

Not having it in the bean at all, is probably better encapsulation-wise.. and "new" vs "existing" is a common requirement to know in Edit Forms & pages, and is really a property of the lifecycle within the Edit Form, not the specific bean type. Outside the Create/Edit pages, it's immaterial.

Long story short: implement it once in your "base EditForm controller", rather than separately in each entity class.

Comment: also a public getter getIsNewCandidate would be fine know so i can make the property private

Comment: Yep, you can have a `public` getter & make the _field_ `protected` or `private`.. I always prefer protected, since it's easier for engineering & debugging.